# Is Drupal 6 compatible with php5.3?

Tags: 6

We have just upgrade our server and now Our drupal 6 sites are not working properly because now the php version has been changed from 5.2 to 5.3.

is there any guide or suggestion about this? how to run a drupal6 with PHP5.3?

Thanks in advance.

Downgrading the php version from 5.3 to 5.2 solves the php problem and apparently the javascript problem as well.

Comment: Core should be fine as long as you have an update-to-date version (see http://groups.drupal.org/node/194883). Contrib modules are another matter altogether, you'll need to look at them on an individual basis. Posting the error messages you're getting would be very useful

Comment: I was scared about this... so ok, let's the modules one by one, keep calm and carry on or hook()... As long as drupal 7 runs on php5.3 and php5.2 would you suggest to swap the php back to version 5.2 and upgrade all the websites to drupal7?

Comment: I had problems with Views 2.x and PHP 5.3.10+. I had to switch Views and related modules to the 3.x branch and a .dev branch for VBO. Hope this helps.

Comment: I had problem everywhere man! Easier downgrade php version and upgrade to D7! less stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements) says:

> Although PHP 5.3 is supported by Drupal 6.14 core and higher (see the release notes for 6.14), some contributed modules may not be compatible with PHP 5.3, and some PHP 5.3 configurations still show warnings with Drupal 6.14; work is ongoing to resolve the latter in [#360605: PHP 5.3 Compatibility](http://drupal.org/node/360605).

The issue linked in the requirements page is actually marked as fixed; this means that Drupal core is completely compatible with PHP 5.3 since Drupal 6.14.